# Making help file errors in Visual C++ 6.0 Standard Edition

Tags: visual-c++

I am trying to compile and build my test program. however, I am getting the following error.

```
Making help file...
'".\makehelp.bat"' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
Error executing c:\windows\system32\cmd.exe.

hpled6_2565.exe - 1 error(s), 0 warning(s)
```

Do you know how I can solve it? I am using Visual C++ 6.0 Standard Edition.

Comment: I have to ask...Is there a reason you are using a version of a compiler that is 17 years old when modern and up-to-date versions exist for free?

Comment: well our company test-program was built using this version, and they haven't upgraded it. other test programs run well in this version.

Comment: I'd start by taking a look at makehelp.bat and making sure that it A) exists and B) still runs properly.

Answer (score 0):

```
'".\makehelp.bat"' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
Error executing c:\windows\system32\cmd.exe.
```

The above seems to indicate that your test program is missing the `makehelp.bat` file.

That in itself is easy to fix, just replace `XYZ` with your project name in the template auto-generated by VC6 (copied below) and save it as `makehelp.bat` in the project directory.

```
@echo off
REM -- First make map file from Microsoft Visual C++ generated resource.h
echo // MAKEHELP.BAT generated Help Map file.  Used by XYZ.HPJ. >"hlp\XYZ.hm"
echo. >>"hlp\XYZ.hm"
echo // Commands (ID_* and IDM_*) >>"hlp\XYZ.hm"
makehm ID_,HID_,0x10000 IDM_,HIDM_,0x10000 resource.h >>"hlp\XYZ.hm"
echo. >>"hlp\XYZ.hm"
echo // Prompts (IDP_*) >>"hlp\XYZ.hm"
makehm IDP_,HIDP_,0x30000 resource.h >>"hlp\XYZ.hm"
echo. >>"hlp\XYZ.hm"
echo // Resources (IDR_*) >>"hlp\XYZ.hm"
makehm IDR_,HIDR_,0x20000 resource.h >>"hlp\XYZ.hm"
echo. >>"hlp\XYZ.hm"
echo // Dialogs (IDD_*) >>"hlp\XYZ.hm"
makehm IDD_,HIDD_,0x20000 resource.h >>"hlp\XYZ.hm"
echo. >>"hlp\XYZ.hm"
echo // Frame Controls (IDW_*) >>"hlp\XYZ.hm"
makehm IDW_,HIDW_,0x50000 resource.h >>"hlp\XYZ.hm"
REM -- Make help for Project XYZ

echo Building Win32 Help files
start /wait hcw /C /E /M "hlp\XYZ.hpj"
if errorlevel 1 goto :Error
if not exist "hlp\XYZ.hlp" goto :Error
if not exist "hlp\XYZ.cnt" goto :Error
echo.
if exist Debug\nul copy "hlp\XYZ.hlp" Debug
if exist Debug\nul copy "hlp\XYZ.cnt" Debug
if exist Release\nul copy "hlp\XYZ.hlp" Release
if exist Release\nul copy "hlp\XYZ.cnt" Release
echo.
goto :done

:Error
echo hlp\XYZ.hpj(1) : error: Problem encountered creating help file

:done
echo.
```

However, for this to work, you also need a `resource.h` following the VC6 resource IDs conventions, plus the respective `.hpj` and `.cnt` files.

Also, you should be aware that even if you get it to work, the end result will be a HLP file that's been deprecated since Vista, and requires a separate WinHlp32 install to be viewable at all (https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/917607).